# Problem with setting values ​in my class's pointers array

Tags: c++, qt, oop

I have created 2 classes ("MainWindow" and "przycisk"). In one of them (MainWindow) I have second class pointers array (przycisk *tab[33][33]). The problem is that when I want to change any value of this array, the program crashes). What am I doing wrong?

**"Main Window" class:**

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
    przycisk *tab[33][33];
    int liczba;
    int bomby;

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

public slots:
    void zmien_liczbe(int li);
    void pokaz_ekran();

};
```

**"przycisk" class:**

```
class przycisk
        :public QPushButton
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    void polacz();
    bool bomba;
    int wart;

public slots:
    void tekst();

};
```

**Code in which I am trying to change the value of "bomba"**

```
    int a,b;
    for(int i=0;i<bombs;i++)
    {

        a=rand()%count;
        b=rand()%count;
        tab[a][b]->bomba=1;
        
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by crash? Is it segmentation fault? Are you sure that elements of tab array is a valid address (pointer) ? Where do you allocate a memory for this elements ?

Comment: Yes, it is a segmentation fault. I am just declaring it inside the class.

Comment: Declaration of pointer is different. You must allocate a memory area with malloc, or new in c++. Otherwise pointer is not useful, it points invalid address. Every element of tab array must point to the allocated address. You may allocate this addresses in the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To allocate memory for tab array elements ;

```
for(int i = 0; i<33; ++i)
    for(int j = 0; j<33; ++j)
        tab[i][j] = new przycisk;
```

You can do this allocation in the constructor.

And also, do not forget the edit the destructor since you are using heap allocated data members.